# Multiple NICband need gateway to each NIC ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking

i have some issue regarding setting up NTP on Ubuntu 16.04.
I have 2 NICs:

```
eth0 192.168.1.1/24 gateway 192.168.1.254 <-- uses for Internet access 
eth1 172.16.0.1/24 gateway 172.16.0.254 <-- used for local client VLAN access
```

However, I cannot access to this server from the client network, and I think this is cause by multiple gateway in one Linux.

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! **:-)** Can another client PC on 172.16.0.0/24 ping that server? Also prlease [edit] your question and provide the output to the `route` command.